# Error in ORACLE UPDATE QUERY 2147217887(80040e21) The system cannot find a message text for the message number 0x80040e21

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, adodb

I am uploading the data in an Excel sheet to an Oracle database using Excel macros. I am getting this error in the execute statement.

I am facing difficulties in debugging this error.

Run Time error: -2147217887(80040e21) The system cannot find a message text for the message number 0x80040e21 in the message file for OraOLEDB

```
 strSQL = "update T_SAP_MSEG set TSM_BWART= ?,TSM_BUDAT_MKPF= ? " _
    & "where TSM_MANDT = ? and TSM_MBLNR= ? and TSM_MJAHR= ? and" _
    & " TSM_ZEILE= ?"

cmd.CommandText = strSQL


Set MyParameter = cmd.CreateParameter("BWART", adVarChar, adParamInput, 3, BWART)
cmd.Parameters.Append MyParameter

Set MyParameter = cmd.CreateParameter("BUDAT_MKPF", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8, BUDAT_MKPF)
cmd.Parameters.Append MyParameter

Set MyParameter = cmd.CreateParameter("MANDT", adVarChar, adParamInput, 3, MANDT)
cmd.Parameters.Append MyParameter

Set MyParameter = cmd.CreateParameter("MBLNR", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, MBLNR)
cmd.Parameters.Append MyParameter

Set MyParameter = cmd.CreateParameter("MJAHR", adVarChar, adParamInput, 4, MJAHR)
cmd.Parameters.Append MyParameter

Set MyParameter = cmd.CreateParameter("ZEILE", adVarChar, adParamInput, 4, ZEILE)
cmd.Parameters.Append MyParameter

    cmd.Execute
```

Comment: You have already asked the same question yesterday, haven't you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Time error: -2147217887(80040e21) The system cannot find a message text for the message number 0x80040e21 in the message file for OraOLEDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344631/run-time-error-214721788780040e21-the-system-cannot-find-a-message-text-for)